# Pay with a different card when using the Pay Later function on Expedia

Tags: online-resources, bookings, hotels, expedia

If I book a hotel at Expedia and choose to pay later at the hotel, can I use a different card than the one I used for the booking to pay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can settle with the property (hotel) directly using any means they accept.  Credit Card, Cash, Check, Points.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can also pay cash.

The actual credit card will be used only for no-show fees, and to screen fake bookings.